# Why can't my Dad join my world on Windows from his Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, windows-10

Me and my dad enjoy playing Minecraft together, but he can't join my LAN world for some reason. But, I can still join his without issues. I've tried turning my firewall off, but it didn't work. What could be the root cause of this problem?